# App causing battery drain, possible caching issue?

Tags: android, caching, battery

Just about finished with my first android app, but I noticed recently a pretty significant battery drain. It happens even after the app is closed, even after it's been force stopped, until the phone is turned off. Logcat is giving me nothing.

I finally managed to get battery historian going and investigated, and while I can't make sense of most of it I did see that the app seems to constantly be spending time caching.

Since I'm still new to this, it's entirely possible I'm saving something wrong, or retrieving something wrong, or just doing something wrong in general, but it's a pretty simple app so there aren't any obvious places to start looking at what's causing this.

I should add this problem seems to happen even if the user only opens the app and closes it, without doing anything at all.

If there's any more information I can provide, I'd be happy to.

Anyone have any ideas on where to start looking for the problem?

Comment: Even after its been forced stopped?  That's a pretty hard break, nothing should be running (thus nothing using power) after that

Comment: I know. It's possible I mis-diagnosed (or rather, the android app statistics misdiagnosed) but even after force stopping the battery usage continued to grow, about 1mAh/minute according to the battery usage statistics in android settings